# Advanced MySQL search query - using RLIKE

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, rlike

Im working on a MySQL search query for a product search module in Joomla/Virtuemart.
I am actually trying to modify an existing MySQL query from using MATCH / AGAINST to using RLIKE, but my modified query gives errors..

Here is the original query with MATCH / AGAINST which has no errors:

```
$searchstring = " +search* +string* +test*";
$query ="SELECT p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name from #__virtuemart_products AS p, #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." AS l WHERE MATCH(product_name,customtitle) AGAINST ('".$searchstring."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND p.published = '1' AND p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id  LIMIT 0,".$prods." union (select p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name from #__virtuemart_products AS p, #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." as l where  MATCH(product_sku) AGAINST ('".$searchstring."' IN BOOLEAN MODE) and p.published = '1'  and p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id LIMIT 0,".$prods.")";
```

Here is my altered query using RLIKE:

```
$searchstring = "search|string|test";
$query ="SELECT p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name from #__virtuemart_products AS p, #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." AS l WHERE product_name,customtitle RLIKE '".$searchstring."' AND p.published = '1' AND p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id LIMIT 0,".$prods." union (select p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name from #__virtuemart_products AS p, #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." as l where product_sku RLIKE '".$searchstring."' and p.published = '1'  and p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id LIMIT 0,".$prods.")";
```

I am out of ideas as to why the RLIKE search query does not work.
I hope someone can point out what I´m doing wrong here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this weird expression in your query:

```
WHERE product_name, customtitle RLIKE '".$searchstring."'
```

Try combining them using `concat()` first:

```
(SELECT p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name
 from #__virtuemart_products p join
      #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." l
      on p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id
 WHERE concat(product_name, customtitle) RLIKE '".$searchstring."' AND
       p.published = '1'
 LIMIT 0,".$prods."
)
union
(select p.virtuemart_product_id, l.product_name
 from #__virtuemart_products p join
      #__virtuemart_products_".VMLANG." l
      on p.virtuemart_product_id = l.virtuemart_product_id
 where product_sku RLIKE '".$searchstring."' and
       p.published = '1'
 LIMIT 0,".$prods.
)
```

You could also compare each one separately:

```
 WHERE (product_name RLIKE '".$searchstring."' OR
        customtitle RLIKE '".$searchstring."' 
       ) AND . . .
```

Note that I also fixed the `join` syntax to use explicit joins.

Comment: That worked perfectly, though I had to make a small fix in the end (it need a double quote after "$prods") like this: $prods."
)

Comment: I have a small side-question.. if I use the search string "test|search" with RLIKE then the query finds everything containing 1 or both 2 words. If I want to only show results when containing both words, how should I formulate the search string?

Comment: @GeniusDesign . . . You can just use `like`:  `col like '%test%' and col like '%search%'`.  There is probably a way to express this as a regular expression, but I'm guessing two comparisons is easier to express.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, there are indeed alot of possibilities. I managed to tweak my query perfectly now and I also had to do a bit of PHP manipulation of the incoming search string to make it work as "AND" instead of "OR", but in the end all worked out